# How to change hosting server for SharePoint Provider Hosted Apps without disturbing the existing users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, hosting

I have created a Provider Hosted App for SharePoint Online. I used Azure hosting server to host my app business logic.

Now, somehow I want to move my Hosting server from Azure to another domain. But my app is already published on Office Store and my users already installed the apps and they are using.

I want to know that how I can change my hosting environment for PHA without disturbing the existing users.

What kind of configuration I will need to change in my App?

I have already gone through [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/501ace7c-2aa6-4c11-98c6-cbecdbd7fd16/change-hosting-server-for-sharepoint-provider-hosted-apps?forum=appsforsharepoint) post, but its not helpful.

Comment: There could be another way, but from where i see it, if you change the domain, then you will have to register the app using new client id and secret. It will be a new app with different client id.

Comment: Thanks :-)That exactly what I thought before putting the question. I hope there should some feasible way for achieving this !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried this practically, but I am sharing based on my understanding. Please feel free to comment if any thing is practically incorrect.

**Approach-1:**

Just configure the new domain with the old domain name. So only hosting location will change, the app will still have valid domain name to redirect.

**Approach-2:**

While registering the Provider Hosted App, we use following URL.

```
https://SiteURL/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx
```

here we provide the `App Domain` and `Redirect URI`. And it gives us a `ClientID` and `ClientSecret` key which we use to configure our Provider Hosted App.

Now we have our `ClientID`. Now lets say our domain has been changed, just go to the following URL

```
https://SiteURL/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx
```

You will get following form

[image]

Just enter you existing `ClientID` and click on **`Lookup`**. It will fetch already existing details.

Just enter the new `Domain` and `RedirectURI` here.

By doing this, the app will still have the existing `ClientID` and domain also get updated.

Just upload the app again in Catalog and your customer will see update of the app after 24 hours, and after updating the app will run from new server.
(During Mean time keep the old server working so that functionality of your app continue working!!!)

**Note:** Again, I haven't verified anything practically, it may not be the feasible solution. Feedbacks are most welcomed as comment.